# How to install oracle XE on Ubuntu with Chef?

Tags: oracle11g, chef-infra, chef-solo

I've been searching for how to install OracleXE on my local ubuntu development box. I have found this recipe https://github.com/leifg/chef-oracle-xe which is doing a decent job, but you still need to run `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure` to config the last step. That requires logging in to the box and run the script. I was wondering what's the correct Chef way of install Oracle XE for development?

Comment: have u tried this!http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0_OrzJk6BY

Comment: Yes I have done that manually. But I want Chef to provision the machine for me instead of doing it manually. I have quite a few machines.

Comment: if you don't mind can you share the link to understand the concept of chef.

Comment: http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview.html Here you go. :-) It's just a automate way to provision a machine.

Comment: The cookbook you linked to does actually already run `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure` and configures OracleXE with the values defined in the cookbook attributes (although the way it does that is a bit awkward). Maybe you have another language other than english in use? Please check if the [expect script](https://github.com/leifg/chef-oracle-xe/blob/master/templates/default/configure_oracle.sh.erb) used by the cookbook looks sane for your environment.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Comment: Instead of rolling with your own please consider http://www.oraopensource.com/oxar/ that in addition of XE also bundles with APEX, ORDS and Node.js. OXAR is open source with MIT license.

Answer (score 3):

The [chef-oracle-xe](https://github.com/leifg/chef-oracle-xe) Chef recipe uses `expect` to configure Oracle. Instead one should use [silent installation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#BABCCGCF). The example response file is found from Oracle XE zip-package. The format is very simple:

```
ORACLE_HTTP_PORT=8080
ORACLE_LISTENER_PORT=1521
ORACLE_PASSWORD=manager
ORACLE_CONFIRM_PASSWORD=manager
ORACLE_DBENABLE=y
```

I use silent installation in [my own](https://github.com/janihur/turnkey-oracle-xe-11g) [TurnKey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/) based Oracle XE installation.

Comment: I have dumped my own Oracle XE installation and I'm currently using http://www.oraopensource.com/oxar/ even I have not yet found use for the other stuff bundled with it.